# Connection Management using @Transactional with Spring JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I am facing a unpredictable outcome when i am inserting data and fetching within the same transaction but in my usecase we have to two different beans one for writing and and for reading data from DB. On production these masterBean(to write) and slaveBean(to read data) are pointing to different urls and on lower environments they are poiting to same urls. We are using Hikari for connection pooling.

```
@Bean("dsSlave")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.slave")
public DataSource slaveDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean("dsMaster")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.master")
public DataSource masterDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean("jdbcTemplateSlave")
public JdbcTemplate slaveJdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(slaveDataSource());
}

@Primary
@Bean("jdbcTemplateMaster")
public JdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(masterDataSource());
}
```

What i am doing is (a pseudo code ) :

```
@Transactional
someMethod() {
jdbcTemplateMaster.update("some data");
jdbcTemplateSlave.query("somedata");
}
```

On production i am not able to fetch data that is committed within the same transaction but on lower environment sometimes i am able to fetch data and sometimes i am not.

any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You are updating the master and reading from the slave. Those are different connections and thus transactions (regardless the fact you have a single `@Transactional`).

Comment: Note: The "weird" behaviour on lower stages is due to the same url (same connection) used - based on the flush behaviour the data written have been propagated (flushed) and can be read or not.

e: manually flushing it before reading or set it to auto will result in "correct" reads.

Comment: @phaen data will be propagated once it is commited right then it should never be read on lower environments as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for explaining the production part can you also please share what is the expected behaviour at lower env where we are creating two beans (master and slave ) which is eventually poiting to the same DB server.

Comment: You cannot read it as it is different datasources, different transactions, different connections. THere is no commit between your update and read as all is in a single transaction. Next to that it will take time to sync the data between master and slave so there is no garantuee it will be directly in sync.

Comment: @M.Deinum there is no data replication on lower env as it is poiiting to same db only the datasources are pointing to same urls (only for production data syncing is reqd as they have different dasources).
(for lower env only i am talking)Even if they are pointing to the same DB server they will be having different connections for master and slave and because transactions are connection specific they are seggregated, is my undersatnding correct??

Comment: Reading is an art... As stated those are still different datasources, different connections and thus different transactions. It doesn't matter if they are the actual same database, you cannot see uncommitted data from one transaction in another one. That is the whole point of transactions, no matter if they are physically on the same machine or half a world apart.